# How can I compress a sequence of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, compression

I have an array which contains data within range -255 to +255.e.g. The array can be like this:

```
  int data[]={234,56,-4,24,56,78,23,89,234,68,-12,-253,45,128};
```

Here, order must be preserved while decompressing e.g. after 1st term 234, 56 must come.

So, what are the ways to compress any arbitrary sequence of numbers for which any repeating pattern can't be observed?

Comment: This is exactly the problem that zip, gz and the other compressors solve.

Comment: Use general purpose compressing algorithm. E.g. Zip.

Comment: Do you have any information about the sequence of numbers besides the range?  If it is an essentially random, uniform distribution over that range, and order is to be preserved, then the best you can do is about 9 bits per entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A range of -255 to 255 means 511 values -> 9 bits. If you take the sign separately, 1 bit for sign and a byte for value.

You can write your array as a byte array, each byte value will be the absolute value of the related int.

In a separate zone (a long, or perhaps a byte array), store the sign bit.

Comment: this is a coding not compression ; the only way to compress is to remove redundancy

Comment: If I could downvote a comment I would. No need to be pendantic: Does the output consume less bits than the input? Yes

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul compression is merely encoding to use less space; aside from that, is this *not* removing redundancy? He is eliminating the *23 extra bits per value that are not needed* -- which, afaik, is what [redundancy __is__](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(information_theory)).

Answer (score 6):

If there are truly no patterns in the data then a useful compression algorithm is impossible. Don't even bother trying!

Of course, in this case because all the numbers are in a restricted range n then you do have a pattern in the bits - namely that your high bits are either all 0 (positive) or all 1 (negative).

Standard compression algorithms like zip would therefore work if you want to compress reasonably effectively (assuming you have a long enough array of numbers to make it worthwhile).

Alternatively you can exploit the fact that you are effectively using 9-bit numbers. So you could roll your own compression algorithm by laying out the numbers as a long stream of 9-bit chunks and putting this into a byte array.

Answer (score 6):

In your situation (when repeating pattern can't be observed), **variable-length coding** may help you.

For example, [Elias gamma-coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding) and [Exponential-Golomb coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential-Golomb_coding). **The general idea - is that small numbers needs only few bits to be encoded.** Exp-Golomb coding is used in the H.264/MPEG-4 AVC video compression standard. It is very easy to encode and decode sequences with it, also it is not very hard to implement this coding.

The way to code all integers is to set up a bijection, mapping integers (0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ...) to (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...) before coding.

For example:

Sequence (after bijection) `[ 0, 2, 5, 8, 5, 2 ]` would be encoded as  `101100110000100100110011` - **As you may see - there is no repeating patterns in this sequence, but it encoded only with 24 bits.**

Short description of decoding process:

1. Read from input stream and count leading zero-bits (until you find non-zero
   bit) -> **zero_bits_count**
2. Read from input stream next **( zero_bits_count + 1 )** bits -> **binary**
3. Convert **binary** to **decimal**
4. Return **( decimal - 1 )**

`1... -> no leading zeros, zero_bits_count = 0 -> read next 1 bit -> [1]... -> [1] is 1 -> 1 - 1 = 0`

`011... -> [0] - one leading zero, zero_bits_count =  1 -> read next 2 bits -> [11]... -> [11] is 3 -> 3 - 1 = 2`

`00110... -> [00] - two leading zeros, zero_bits_count = 2 -> read next 3 bits -> [110]... -> [110] is 6 -> 6 - 1 = 5`

etc.

Comment: But in this range [ 0, 2, 5, 8, 5, 2 ], all no. are less than 16.So 4 bits will be required for each digit.i.e. total 6*4=24 bits will be required.So,where's the compression?

Comment: If the values are uniformly distributed, then variable-length coding will expand the data larger than 9 bits per value.  Variable-length coding would only be useful if the smaller values are considerably more likely than the larger values.

Comment: @Debadyuti Maiti I agree with Mark Adler. It's just a way to compact sequence, where are lots of small values (but large values are present too). In this case it would be better vs. coding with predefined length (because you'll need to expand length of code for large values, and it would be applied for small values too).

Comment: @Debadyuti Maiti Another example: using `variable length` codes `[0,2,5,8,5,2,255,3,4,20]` -> would be encoded to `60-bits` sequence. But if you'll decide use bitstring with fixed length for each value -> you'll need `8-bit per value` (because of value 255). And `[0,2,5,8,5,2,255,3,4,20]` would be encoded to `80-bits` sequence. You'll get benefit only if small values are frequent.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are essentially random and uniformly distributed, and order is to be preserved, then the best you can do is about 9 bits per symbol.  At 9 bits, a single 9 bit value will be unused, i.e. -256 in a 2's complement representation.  That is convenient, since you can use that as an end symbol to mark the end of the list.  Then you have also coded the length of the list, which would be needed somehow anyway.